# How can I monitor or control a shared folder on our network?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, network-share

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server that has about 10 folders in it. Well, someone accidentally deleted an entire folder called "Development". (all are Win7 users)

1. Is there a way to prevent this, but still allow EVERY user full
   access to view, copy, delete (within the folder), and add to this
   folder?
2. Is there a way to find out WHO deleted it?
3. Is there a way to get something like 3 prompts when someone tries to
   delete the ENTIRE folder again?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe. http://serverfault.com/questions/61242/how-can-i-audit-a-file-to-see-who-deleted-it

Comment: I fear that three prompts will not work either. Sometimes people will have to delete a folder. After a few correctly deleted folders they will have acquired the habit of pressing just ENTER three times without thinking about it.

Comment: It's ok if they can delete everything in the folder, just not the folder itself?

Comment: Yes and no. It's not, but that's very very unlikely compared to deleting the whole folder. You connect to the S: drive, and under that, there's 10 folders. Within those folders, each has hundreds of folders. So it would be difficult to even select all of those, much less delete them compared to just selecting ONE of the "top" folders on S:.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. A user can't be prevented from deleting files and folders while having Full permission to said files and folders.
2. Not for the current event, but if you enable auditing you'll be able to for future events.
3. Not unless you rewrite the OS.
4. BONUS - This is precisely why it's important to have regular, reliable backups of your data.

Comment: addition to #4: In a windows environment, there is a high degree of possibility that the shadow-copy service is installed and has been making backups since the server was installed.  Try right-clicking on the empty share (where the missing folder should be) and go to properties... and look for the "Previous Versions" tab.  From there, you can open a view into it's previous state and copy the missing folder back.